# How to use a structure as a pointer and as an structure in functions

Tags: c, pointers

I've got a code where I should use some functions,one of them has a prototype like this: void writeR(RESISTOR) and the other like this: void write(RESISTOR *,int)
The writeR function should be called inside the write function,but I don't know how to use it because I have a pointer type RESISTOR in all functions besides the writeR.
Should I make a new value type RESISTOR without a pointer and then call that function or something else?

P.S. the writeR function is called to input the resistance and the resistor no. and is being used in loop.

P.P.S. this is the error I get when I try to compile the program 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'otp1' used

```
void write(RESISTOR *otp, int n)
{
    RESISTOR otp1;
    int i;
    printf("\nRB. KATALOSKI BROJ           R");
    printf("\n--- --------------- ----------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d.",i + 1);
        writeR(otp1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is because you don't initialize variable `opt1` which is being passed to function which maybe used in your program .

Comment: Do not call your function `write()` in C. That's also the name of a [basic IO function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) used to *write* data to a file descriptor.  Using the same symbol name can lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the real name is not write nor writeR I've just translated it to English so you guys could better understand what the function has to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use indirection operator `*` to access the structur your pointer references.

```
void write(RESISTOR *otp, int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nRB. KATALOSKI BROJ           R");
    printf("\n--- --------------- ----------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d.",i + 1);
        writeR(*otp);
            // ^^^
    }
}
```

Comment: The writeR function can't use a pointer,I've tried it and I'm getting this error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _writeR referenced in function _write